# Firebase firestore only allow read if user has exact document ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way for a user to only be able to read a document only if they have the exact document ID?

```js
// should fail:
db.collection(`docs`).get()

// should succeed:
db.doc(`docs/${docId}`).get()
```

It'll be like how if you have link sharing on in a Google Doc and you can only access the Doc if you have the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible, and actually quite easy once you realize that `read` in your security rules is a shorthand for two more granular operations: `list` and `get`.

So if you only allow `get`, the user must know a specific document ID, and they can't get the entire collection or query it.

Also see the documentation on [granular security rules operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).